# How can I use For, While, Repeat functions with changing rep times

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, repeat

**How can i print following code with For, While and Repeat functions in R?**

> [1] 9 9 9 9 9
>
> [1] 7 7 7
>
> [1] 5
>
> [1] 3 3 3
>
> [1] 1 1 1 1 1

**With 2 hours of trial, I've discovered following code works to print above result**

> x<-c(5,0,3,0,1,0,3,0,5,0)
>
> for(i in 10:1) {   if(!i %%2) {    next   }
>
> print(rep(i,x[i]))
>
> }

**while func**

> t<-c(5,0,3,0,1,0,3,0,5)
>
> i<-9
>
> while(i>=1)
>
> {print(rep(i,t[i]))
>
> i<-i-2}

**repeat**

> i<-9
>   repeat{if(i<1)
>   break
>    print(rep(i,t[i]))
>   i<- i-2}

**but it seems so unnatural for me.
Is there any more compact or easier way to solve the problem?**

Comment: use `rep` directly? `rep(9:0, x)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rep` directly using `x` as `times` argument

```
rep(9:0, x)
#[1] 9 9 9 9 9 7 7 7 5 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1
```

If you want them as list you can do

```
mapply(rep, (9:0)[x > 0], x[x > 0])

#[[1]]
#[1] 9 9 9 9 9

#[[2]]
#[1] 7 7 7

#[[3]]
#[1] 5

#[[4]]
#[1] 3 3 3

#[[5]]
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: thanks but could you give me more specific code?
Problem is... it has to be different row...

Comment: @5-HTPPlus I have updated the answer so that you get each one of them as separate list.

Answer (score 0):

We can pass a vector of input to replicate in `rep`

```
x1 <- rep(c(9, 7, 5, 3, 1), c(5, 3 ,1, 3, 5))
#[1] 9 9 9 9 9 7 7 7 5 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1
```

and then `split` based on the replicate

```
split(x1, factor(x1, levels = unique(x1)))
#$`9`
#[1] 9 9 9 9 9

#$`7`
#[1] 7 7 7

#$`5`
#[1] 5

#$`3`
#[1] 3 3 3

#$`1`
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1
```